# Trying to print from web page (PWA app) using ipp protocol

Tags: javascript, printing, cups

I'm trying to print raw text from a web page (PWA app). I own a USB printer configured in CUPS on the same machine showing the web page - of course I'm writing Javascript code.
I built a fetch() request like:

```
fetch('http://'+ip+':'+port+'/printers/'+printer, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/ipp'
      },
    body: reqBody
    })
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(response => console.error(response))
```

Into the reqBody variable I stored an ipp request.
The response is (from javascript console):

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
 body: (...)
 bodyUsed: false
 headers: Headers {}
 ok: false
 redirected: false
 status: 0
 statusText: ""
 type: "opaque"
 url: ""
```

In the Respose view I see the CUPS web page (so HTML code) .. in my understanding it should be ipp data in a HTTP packet, should it?

Where is my error?
thanks

Comment: Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) says that in 'no-cors' only a couple of Content-Type are allowed... but in cors mode I receive an error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP modulre for Apache was not enabled  :(

Comment: Another reason was that "mode: 'no-cors'" caused 'opaque' response